# AvPlayer is unable to play sound in device

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avplayer, swift4

My code perfectly works fine in the simulator and it streams the url without any issue. But when plugged to the actual device it doesnt play the audio. My code as bellow

```
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
var player: AVPlayer?

func initPlayer() {
    let url:URL = URL(string:"https://storage.googleapis.com/purelightdatabucket/samples%2F60-Energy%20UPLIFT.mp3")!
    self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    self.player=AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem!)
    let playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player!)
    playerLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 50) // actually this player layer is not visible
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
}
```

Comment: No when i play an audio from the music player it plays perfectly. Plus the issue is only with iphone 6 i guess. on 7 it works. can figure out the reason

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put this code in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
 do {
       try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
       try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
 } catch {
     print(error)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this too :

You need to add `AVKit` & `AVFoundation` to your `frameworks` path and import them :

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player = AVPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "https://storage.googleapis.com/purelightdatabucket/samples%2F60-Energy%20UPLIFT.mp3")!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player.play()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```